# Valid JSON Results in PHP json_decode Throwing A Syntax Error

Tags: php, json

Welp, I see quite a few hits on this, but none seem to answer my question.

I have a REST method that returns this JSON:

This is the exact string in the $result variable, below:

```
{"people":{"people":{"new_user":{"id":7,"name":"Marvin","lang":"en","read_token":1,"write_token":11,"last_access":"2018-06-17 17:00:02","writeable":true,"surname":"Martian","middle_name":"D","given_name":"Marvin","nickname":"Angry Little Fella","payload":"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","payload_type":"image\/svg+xml;base64","associated_login":{"id":11,"name":"Marvin","lang":"en","login_id":"Marvin","write_token":11,"last_access":"2018-06-17 17:00:02","writeable":true,"user_object_id":7,"security_tokens":[11],"password":"6f2T8rK4"}}}}}
```

Yeah, it's big and fugly, but it is completely valid.

When I feed it to [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com), I get a nice green bar and well-formatted JSON:

```
{
  "people": {
      "people": {
          "new_user": {
              "id": 7,
              "name": "Marvin",
              "lang": "en",
              "read_token": 1,
              "write_token": 11,
              "last_access": "2018-06-17 16:56:49",
              "writeable": true,
              "surname": "Martian",
              "middle_name": "D",
              "given_name": "Marvin",
              "nickname": "Angry Little Fella",
              "payload": "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",
              "payload_type": "image\/svg+xml;base64",
              "associated_login": {
                  "id": 11,
                  "name": "Marvin",
                  "lang": "en",
                  "login_id": "Marvin",
                  "write_token": 11,
                  "last_access": "2018-06-17 16:56:49",
                  "writeable": true,
                  "user_object_id": 7,
                  "security_tokens": [11],
                  "password": "TuqWG+%y"
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Nevertheless, feeding this JSON to PHP 7.2.1's [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function keeps returning a [JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) error (bad syntax).

I think the issue may be with the data in the SVG file, but that is valid Base64 data. It should be fine in JSON.

I tried all the various solutions mentioned in other posts, but still no dice.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Here's the PHP code that I run it through:

```
echo('RESULT:<pre>');
var_dump(json_decode($result));
switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}
echo('</pre>');
```

That code, in my server/laptop, is what's exposing it.

**UPDATE 2:** This is the dump from my cURL routine, showing the response:

```
string(10159) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 Jun 2018 17:29:35 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1
Content-Length: 10007
Content-Type: application/json

{"people":{"people":{"new_user":{"id":7,"name":"Marvin","lang":"en","read_token":1,"write_token":11,"last_access":"2018-06-17 17:29:35","writeable":true,"surname":"Martian","middle_name":"D","given_name":"Marvin","nickname":"Angry Little Fella","payload":"<REMOVED FOR BREVITY>","payload_type":"image\/svg+xml;base64","associated_login":{"id":11,"name":"Marvin","lang":"en","login_id":"Marvin","write_token":11,"last_access":"2018-06-17 17:29:35","writeable":true,"user_object_id":7,"security_tokens":[11],"password":"1Jq6$oT0"}}}}}"
```

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code here? I tried this is the php console and it decoded fine.

Comment: I did. I think the issue may be MAMP. It seems to work everywhere else, and it works fine on my laptop with other images (some, much larger). It's not a showstopper, and I have bigger fish to fry, so I'm punting for now.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the exact response you receive, `echo $result`. If that's perfectly valid JSON-code, the problem is not in your code, but in your set-up.

Comment: I agree. I think that I need to look at some of the games I've played with the command-line, as well as the setup. I would not be surprised if I cheesed it up by being a bit too clever for my own good. In the past, I have so thoroughly hosed my machine by playing fast and loose with CLI, that I have had to take off and nuke it from orbit, as that was the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I wanted to let y'all know what happened. It ain't an answer, but it will be the one I greencheck.

I took off and nuked it from orbit, and now it works.

I have to assume that I did something that sent invisible characters that didn't make it into copy and paste, so the JSONLint never saw them. I'll bet if I had cURLed or wgetted straight from the test harness, it would have borked.

This is a warning to me: Don't get too feisty with the CLI. I'm maybe not as hot at this stuff as I'd like to think.

Thanks for the help, folks.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767652/do-php-curl-options-curlopt-header-and-curlopt-returntransfer-conflict/35767895#35767895

Comment: Hey, that’s great! Thanks!